# How to retrieve files from git cache?

Tags: git, github

I have created a new repo in remote github and try pushing the local files after initial commit. Owing to storage size limit push got failed. Somehow the files in local disk were missing(ls -alrt lists only the empty dirs). Now those files were neither available in local disk (including trash) nor available in remote git. However, it is available in local git cache which is getting displayed in Git Desktop.

Please let me know how to retrieve them from Git Cache to local disk.

Details:
Mac OS Sierra - 10.12 ++ Git - 2.19.0 ++ Github Desktop - 1.5.0

[Github Desktop displaying the content from cache(?)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nek1.png)

git log -a
commit d1dd6d3c1ae871ba0ea26ae4d819c9dd2b6d1a8e (HEAD -> master)
Author: A…<…com>
Date:   Wed Nov 14 15:34:11 2018 -0700

```
Revert "intial commit"

This reverts commit 9233a2e0fd96f7837d1cdf198795a9f57d3d7f4b.
```

commit 052adad2e2f31ed3eced327ae4893a8c0468dce4
Author: A…<…com>
Date:   Wed Nov 14 15:34:09 2018 -0700

```
Revert "initial commit"

This reverts commit 821e08a29a5cb908b187230318ee0b9f352a63cc.
```

commit c198ae2456bc9b0805fb35bfd08b962dbcf75173
Author: A…<…com>
Date:   Wed Nov 14 15:34:05 2018 -0700

```
Revert "initial commit"

This reverts commit 1e66da35ab95d3cbe63ed597c8aeb409cb7ad4af.
```

commit 1393929072b7454387bac46c4a7b81bb69b6f9ca
Author: A…<…com>
Date:   Wed Nov 14 15:31:17 2018 -0700

```
added jmx files
```

commit 9233a2e0fd96f7837d1cdf198795a9f57d3d7f4b
Author: A…<…com>
Date:   Wed Nov 14 15:29:49 2018 -0700

```
intial commit
```

commit 821e08a29a5cb908b187230318ee0b9f352a63cc
Author: ……..MacBook-Pro.local>
Date:   Wed Nov 14 15:17:56 2018 -0700

```
initial commit
```

commit 1e66da35ab95d3cbe63ed597c8aeb409cb7ad4af
Author: ……..MacBook-Pro.local>
Date:   Wed Nov 14 15:07:28 2018 -0700

```
initial commit
```

1+  Stopped                 git log -a

$ git status

On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)

```
xxxx/xxxxx-Release/TestResults/
xxxx/xxxxRelease/
xxxx/xxxx-Release/
xxxx/xxRelease/TestResults/
xxxxxx-Release/TestResults/
```

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Git Desktop. Can you give a screenshot to show what you see?

Comment: what is git cache?

Comment: Hi!  from your terminal, the output of `git status` would be helpful

Comment: I have added the output of git log -a in addition to git status

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're referring to 'Cache' is git internal's filesystem snapshot of commit. (i.e. committed files)

If that's correct, `git reset --hard 1e96da3` and `git clean -f`(optional if you want to remove all untracked files).

If you want to recover some commits that are lost, then `git reflog` to get lost commits' SHA-1 hash value and `git reset --hard SHA-1`.